# How to pass a single backslash inside an environment variable in docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to pass an environment variable to docker. This variable is to be (re-)interpreted by the application running inside docker.

This variable is supposed to contain a comma-separated list, but my list-elements contain commas themselves.

I'm trying to escape the commas inside the list-elements, and use unescaped commas to separate the elements.

My list-elements are the distinguished names of some certificates (hence they contain commas).

I tried passing the environment variable wrapped in single quotes, double quotes, escaping my backslash and unescaping it. Neither of these scenarios left me with a single backslash:

```
# Single quote, single backslash
me@me:~$ docker run --rm --name commatest -d -e PSEUDO_LIST='CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2' busybox sleep 1000; docker inspect commatest | grep PSEUDO_LIST; docker stop commatest;
ed09a7570c83a6a2d9b7d888eb7c83ee763a7a60f1222d1ad0ba4e070cb73de6
                "PSEUDO_LIST=CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2",
commatest

# Single quote, double backslash
me@me:~$ docker run --rm --name commatest -d -e PSEUDO_LIST='CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2' busybox sleep 1000; docker inspect commatest | grep PSEUDO_LIST; docker stop commatest;
dedb0c4eed40454af55519df864468602785ab247c0e6ff85943d56c1f784aa1
                "PSEUDO_LIST=CN=cn\\\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\\\,OU=ou2",
commatest

# Double quote, single backslash
me@me:~$ docker run --rm --name commatest -d -e PSEUDO_LIST="CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2" busybox sleep 1000; docker inspect commatest | grep PSEUDO_LIST; docker stop commatest;
31e1051926400ca0b02ddd2ad17146c2a46ba62dd2a724afee5aba47f243551e
                "PSEUDO_LIST=CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2",
commatest

# Double quote, double backslash
me@me:~$ docker run --rm --name commatest -d -e PSEUDO_LIST="CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2" busybox sleep 1000; docker inspect commatest | grep PSEUDO_LIST; docker stop commatest;
ae65699be53810f773f0d42c43ab1f884c4d7111c2c22ec3a489a19b534d0dd4
                "PSEUDO_LIST=CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2",
commatest
```

The default behaviour in bash is to only show two backslashes in this scenario: `'\\'`, but this is obviously not the same for docker:

```
# Single quote, single backslash
me@me:~$ PSEUDO_LIST='CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2'; echo "${PSEUDO_LIST}"
CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2

# Single quote, double backslash
me@me:~$ PSEUDO_LIST='CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2'; echo "${PSEUDO_LIST}"
CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2
alin@Touchbar-Monstrosity:~$

# Double quote, single backslash
me@me:~$ PSEUDO_LIST="CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2"; echo "${PSEUDO_LIST}"
CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2

# Double quote, double backslash
me@me:~$ PSEUDO_LIST="CN=cn\\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\\,OU=ou2"; echo "${PSEUDO_LIST}"
CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2
```

Extra info:

- Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
- OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

I could replicate this on our linux servers:

- Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77156
- OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes are there because you're grepping through JSON output, and backslashes need to be escaped in JSON strings.

If you print the environment variable directly you'll see the backslashes aren't actually doubled:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -e PSEUDO_LIST='CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2' busybox sh -c 'echo "$PSEUDO_LIST"'
CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2
```

Alternatively, use a JSON-aware tool such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to print the raw environment variable value:

```
$ docker inspect commatest | jq -r '.[].Config.Env[0]'
PSEUDO_LIST=CN=cn\,OU=ou,CN=cn2\,OU=ou2
```